# Cannot view source on bank account website - how to replicate?

Tags: asp.net, iis, browser-cache

I am curious about how to replicate the inability for a user to view source on a web page.  It appears that there is a form resubmission that occurs in the background and cache has been invalidated - something like that.

In a IIS/.Net MVC environment, how can this be replicated?  Is this an IIS-level setting and/or how can it also be implemented on the web server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, aside from Flash and other plug-ins, three is no way to prevent a savvy user from viewing the source of a web page. Likely the site in question is disabling browser caching via http headers, and using javascript to prevent users from viewing the source. You can read up on cache-control via headers [here](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CONTROL).

A savvy user can always view http traffic via the browser console. These steps may stop your casual user (who probably doesn't care about source anyway) and ensure that the user is always viewing the latest version of the page, but that's about it. No security or protection is actually occurring.